# Testing application using ActivityInstrumentationcase2

Tags: android, automated-tests

when I am testing my application using ActivityInstrumentationcase2 on my emulator it is working fine, but when i run it on the device it is showing

> java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

but I have given that permission in the manifest file.

My code is:

```
package cybercom.datamatics.baba.test;

import static android.test.ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.test.TouchUtils;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;
import android.view.View;
import cybercom.datamatics.baba.CDIS_SMSActivity;
import cybercom.datamatics.baba.Compose;

public class CDIS_SMSTests extends InstrumentationTestCase 
{
    @MediumTest

    public void testActivity()
    {
        Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
        Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor =instrumentation.addMonitor(CDIS_SMSActivity.class.getName(),null,false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setClassName(instrumentation.getTargetContext(),CDIS_SMSActivity.class.getName());
        instrumentation.startActivitySync(intent);

        Activity currentActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor,5);
        assertNotNull(currentActivity);
        View view = currentActivity.findViewById(cybercom.datamatics.baba.R.id.Composemessage);
        assertNotNull(view);
        View origin = currentActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        assertOnScreen(origin, view);

        instrumentation.removeMonitor(monitor);     
        monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(Compose.class.getName(),null,false);       
        Intent ointent = new Intent();
        ointent.setClassName(instrumentation.getTargetContext(),Compose.class.getName());
        ointent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        instrumentation.startActivitySync(ointent);     
        Activity nextActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor,5);
        assertNotNull(nextActivity);

        View numberview = nextActivity.findViewById(cybercom.datamatics.baba.R.id.number);
        assertNotNull(numberview);
        View nextview = nextActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        assertOnScreen(nextview, numberview);       
        TouchUtils.clickView(this,numberview);
        instrumentation.sendStringSync("9964973058");

        View messageview = nextActivity.findViewById(cybercom.datamatics.baba.R.id.message);
        assertNotNull(messageview);
        TouchUtils.clickView(this,messageview);
        assertOnScreen(nextview, messageview);

        instrumentation.sendStringSync("hi");       
        View sendview = nextActivity.findViewById(cybercom.datamatics.baba.R.id.send);
        assertNotNull(sendview);
        assertOnScreen(nextview, sendview);
        TouchUtils.clickView(this,sendview);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are clicking where you think you are - in my case this was using the Robotium method `Solo.clickOnView`.

When I debugged into the code, I found the `View.getLocationOnScreen` method for the view I was trying to click was populating the values as 0,0, which is clearly outside the bounds of my app (and yours). I'm still not sure why the view was reporting these values, but it was a child of a `GridView` inside a `DialogFragment`, and thankfully I could work out the correct offsets using the `GridView`, the code to get the correct screen location from such a view is as below:

```
private int[] getLocationOnScreen(View view) {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
    int[] xy = new int[2];
    View viewParent = (View) view.getParent();
    viewParent.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    xy[0] += r.left;
    xy[1] += r.top;
    viewParent.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
    xy[0] -= r.left;
    xy[1] -= r.top;
    return xy;
}
```

Comment: You don't need parent to get location on screen for view. int[] xy = new int[2]; view.getLocationOnScreen(xy); return xy; is enough. By the way it doesn't provide answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also happens with emulator.

you have to check that your screen is not locked.
When screen is locked, the app you are testing doesn't have the focus, so UI commands are sent to the lockscreen, not to your application. This raises the security exception.

Adding the permission would not fix the problem, the only solution is to unlock the screen manually or programmaticaly.